# What is an "Optical Axis Rod"?

Tags: terminology, cnc

I'm in the process of designing a CNC/3d printer and I came across the term "Optical Axis rod" which seems to be the "standard" rod printers like Prusa use. But I can't find anywhere what the difference between just a "machined rod" and "Optical axis rod" actually is. Is there a tolerance difference? Is it the method it has been determined to be straight? Is it meant for optical machines?